# How to filter out Hibernate log entries

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, orm, configuration

I'm using hibernate 3.5.0-* and I get a lot of log entries (on my standard output) that I'd like to get rid off.

I couldn't figure out where it comes from but I suspect Hibernate might be responsible for generating it.

It looks like:

```
> orderByFragment(order-by)
  > sortSpecification({sort specification})
   > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
    > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.lastname)
    < sortKey(null)
   < sortKeySpecification(asc)
   > orderingSpecification(asc)
   < orderingSpecification(null)
  < sortSpecification(null)
...
```

Anybody knows where it comes from and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have set a default TRACE log level.

Try setting it to WARN instead:

- Logback/Log4j2

  ```
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn"/>
  ```
- Log4j

  ```
  <logger name="org.hibernate">
     <level value="warn"/> 
  </logger>
  ```

Comment: Worth clarifying that this only works from 3.5.2 onwards, as prior to this the Hibernate code was printing to standard out, not the logger. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5064

Comment: Thanks for the clarification